# How To Put 2D Array Data To The String Variable in C# Web App?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi all i have a array like

```
string[,] terms;
```

if i want to put this array data to the string variable in this format string Va="23,85,69"
such that 2D array have two type of data "name" and "Address" then both will get in separate string variable 
hopes for your reply..

Comment: you want the name and address of all array index in one string or separate strings ?

Comment: Yup i want the name of all array index in one string and all array index address in  another string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string result = string.Join(",", 
                    Enumerable.Range(0, terms.GetLength(0))
                       .SelectMany(i => Enumerable.Range(0, terms.GetLength(1))
                                           .Select(j => terms[i, j])));
```

**EDIT**: Non-LINQ version:

```
    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    for (var i = 0; i < terms.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < terms.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            result.Add(terms[i, j]);
        }
    }
    string output = string.Join(",", result);
```

Comment: i am not willing to use Linq is ther any alternate as i am trying to use string builder like,                                    for (int a = 0; a < output.Tables[0].Rows.Count; a++)
                {
                    DateBuider.Append(terms[a, 0]);
                    DateBuider.Append(',');
                }  But how would we remove the ',' after the last data entry in string buider?

Comment: thanks for your reply i have done it by using this Piece of code,

StringBuilder powerBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                for (int a = 0; a < output.Tables[0].Rows.Count; a++)
                {
                    powerBuilder.Append(terms[a, 1]);
                    powerBuilder.Append(',');
                }
                powerBuilder.Remove(powerBuilder.Length - 1, 1);

Comment: thanks for your reply i have done it by using this Piece of code,

StringBuilder powerBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                for (int a = 0; a < output.Tables[0].Rows.Count; a++)
                {
                    powerBuilder.Append(terms[a, 1]);
                    powerBuilder.Append(',');
                }
                powerBuilder.Remove(powerBuilder.Length - 1, 1);